# Facebook breaking changes July 2013 ('page_id' -> 'target_id')

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
The 'page_id' field in the checkin FQL table. Please use 'target_id' instead.
```

I understand what it means, but I don't know what I have to meet the requirements of this ('page_id' -> 'target_id'). I was searching in my code and I can find directly query to this field. I looked to Facebook SDK as well, but I cound't find it neither. I'm search for HTML, javascript, but I still can't find it.

I used in my app retriving user datas in scope - `email,user_likes,publish_stream` and checking if user like specified page.

Maybe someone know what has to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue to all of my apps. I am not using FQL at all. As I get it it's just a notice and if you update your app details you wont have a problem. Just tick the July 2013 option and you are OK.

If anyone has a different solution please write it here.